# Trabalhando com app routing no angular

Tags: angular, rotas, componentes

Minha aplicação começa no AppComponent, no AppComponent eu defini o `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>`

Defini as seguintes rotas:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];


const loginRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'registrar', component: RegistrarComponent}
];
```

Meu login component tem um wrapper com bordas e tudo mais, e eu gostaria de que quando clicasse no botão "registrar", o conteúdo que está dentro do wrapper trocar para o conteúdo da rota 'registrar'.

Para isso eu preciso colocar o router-outlet dentro do wrapper?
Talvez colocar o wrapper no app component??

Estou confuso quanto as rotas.

Comment: A tag `<router-outlet>` é apenas uma marcação para onde os elementos devem aparecer no browser. Todo componente irá aparecer logo abaixo dessa tag. Acredito que você deverá fazer um segundo *outlet* dentro do wrapper e anexar as trocas de rotas a esse segundo.

Comment: Inclusive eu tenho um problema bastante similar ao seu. Vou implementar aqui e depois retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Após quebrar um pouco a minha cabeça (e pesquisar um pouco), consegui fazer algo similar ao que você quer.

Minha aplicação tem uma barra de navegação que eu quero deixar ela no topo o tempo todo, mas que ela deveria desaparecer na tela de login.

Meu app html template era mais ou menos assim:

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Isso fazia com que a barra aparecesse depois da tela de login, mas caso eu voltasse para a "tela inicial" por algum link, a barra continuava na página. Então eu mudei para isso aqui:

```
<router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Com a adição de uma rota:

```
{path: 'home', component: NavBarComponent, outlet: 'navbar'}
```

Agora, quando se trata de mudar rotas, você pode usar dois modos:

No routerLink (dentro do HTML), usar a seguinte forma:

```
[routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: ['caminho'], navbar: ['caminho']}}]"
```

E nos componentes (TypeScript), da seguinte forma:

```
router.navigate([{outlets: {primary: 'caminho', navbar: 'caminho'}}]);
```

Agora, partindo da descrição do seu problema, o router-outlet primário deve ficar **FORA** do wrapper (dentro do app.component.html) e o router-outlet auxiliar dentro do wrapper. Você vai fazer as alterações de rota usando o auxiliar.

Nota:

A barra de endereços vai ficar diferente, algo como

```
    localhost:4200/home(navbar:home)
```

Onde `localhost:4200/home` é a rota do outlet primário e `navbar:home` é a rota dos outlets auxiliares